# How do you set featured images for social platforms like LinkedIn, Twitter, and Facebook to pull into previews?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing landing pages for my company and I have had people ask me if I can set a featured image so that when they link to the page on their social platforms it gets pulled in and displays a preview next to the page title and description. Does anyone have experience with this? I am familiar with how to accomplish this with Wordpress but not with solely HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set meta tags on your webpage that can be read by each network in question.  These go in the `<head>` section of your webpage.  For example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="European Travel Destinations">
<meta property="og:description" content="Offering tour packages for individuals or groups.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
```

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/) has a good reference for different meta tags and how they are processed.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for that. It has been bugging me for a while.